# why do we can't call this() method inside a normal method in java?

Tags: java

Should we need to use this() method always inside a constructor?? Is it possible to call this() inside a non-static method in a class?

```
class A{
  void display(){
     this();
     System.out.println("hi");
  }
}
```

Why can't we do something like this?
I'm learning how to apply this(). So my question may be so easy. But thanks for any help that you give for understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this()` invokes the parameter-less constructor of a class. It can only be invoked from a different constructor of the same class. And it must be the first statement in the constructor body.

You can't invoke it from a regular method for the same reason you can't invoke any constructor as if it was a regular method. Constructors are only invoked to initialize a new instance of a class (created by using the `new` keyword or the `newInstance` method of the `Class` class).